# Displaying loading pop up that can pass custom value to next page

Tags: javascript, html

I am set with a few different tasks. I need a pop up showing loading til the next page which needs the value that the current HTML img has in the onclick even. I have managed to display the loading image but it is on the parent page and not in a pop up, it will show loading then reset the parent page. There is an option to pick multiple values 1-3 but they are all going to the same onclick even in the HTML on the image 
onclick="HRT.CODE(1)", onclick="HRT.CODE(2)" ect...

Not much to go on code wise

Currently I am have the following,

HTML

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  $(this).after("<img src='Images/loading-logo.gif' alt='loading'/>").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=""><img id="RCLookup" name="RCLookup" alt="" src="images/search_icon_resize.png" onload="" onclick="fCW.fS(1);" /></a>
```

So I tested the theory of the next page displaying with out a value and duplicating the behavior I am getting with the code I currently have and although it needs a value the next page will not even display and I am getting errors in the console. So leaves me to just put the loading img in a separate pop up while the next page is loading and still pass the value from the onclick even in the img HTML to the next page. Maybe an onclick="function(1)" passing to some JS to show the pop up image then call fCW.fS(val) from the function??

Comment: what is u r requirement ?

Comment: I am needing to display a pop up instead of having the image on the parent screen, along with pass a value through the while loading pop up to the next page so the next page will know what to do, unfortunately most of the loading pop ups I have found searching do not have this ability. I would even look at adding an additional screen to the application just for the loading pop up if that would make it easier. I didnt entirely understand your question but I hope this helps.

Comment: So I tested the theory of the next page displaying with out a value and duplicating the behavior I am getting with the code I currently have and although it needs a value the next page will not even display and I am getting errors in the console. So leaves me to just put the loading img in a separate pop up while the next page is loading and still pass the value from the onclick even in the img HTML to the next page. Maybe an onclick="function(1)" passing to some JS to show the pop up image then call fCW.fS(val) from the function??